# Class library path in MVC application

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have a .net MVC 5 application. The solution consists of 2 projects, the MVC project and a class library.

When I'm calling `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory` from my class library, the path points to the MVC project. What method should I use to get the path to my class library? I've tried various methods from SO threads without success.

Answer (score 3):

During runtime, your class library DLL reside in the BIN directory that the folder the MVC project is in, so it won't refer to the actual project folder.  If you are looking to access a resource or file or something, it should be in the MVC project (which there are ways to copy).

I would need more context to provide a better answer.

Comment: Makes sense. What about accessing the class library root using `Path.GetFullPath(Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, "../TheClassLib")`?

Comment: Just to understand better, what in that folder are you trying to get to?

Answer (score 0):

> What method should I use to get the path to my class library?

[`GetExecutingAssembly`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.assembly.getexecutingassembly(v=vs.110).aspx) could be used for this purpose I believe and could be *drilled down* for more details:

```
// Gets the assembly that contains the code that is currently executing.
var assembly = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
```